# Why can't my device see an ad-hoc WiFi network?

Tags: wi-fi, ad-hoc-networks

I am trying to connect my Galaxy Tab to the Internet through an ad-hoc network made via my PC.
The PC ad-hoc settings are fine because I can use it from my iPhone and other devices.

Answer (score 8):

Android has issues connecting to adhoc networks. [Here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4117/how-to-share-internet-among-2-android-devices/4147#4147) is a link to a fix someone else here used to get his tablet to connect to a adhoc network. Also [this](http://www.slatedroid.com/index.php?topic=3598.15) is the link to the thread he got his information from.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using any virtual router app on your PC, try running
   these two commands - it might work:

```
netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=SSIDNAME key=YOURPASSWORD 

netsh wlan start hostednetwork
```

- Make sure you run these commands in elevated (administrator) command
  prompt.
- If you get any error after running the second command; something like - "The hosted network couldn't be started. The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.", go to `Device Manager > Network Adaptors` select your network adaptor, right click and select Disable. Again select the same and enable.
- Try running both the above commands again.

Comment: Thanks, it worked without problems. I can't see why the visual interface only allows ad hoc networks and not this...

Comment: Actually it only worked in enabling the network, but I later realized it isn't sharing the internet connection, how to do it?