# Is the Samsung Galaxy Tab 10 really incapable of connecting to ad hoc Wi-Fi?

Tags: windows, wi-fi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does any version of Android support ad-hoc connections?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/does-any-version-of-android-support-ad-hoc-connections)
>   [Why can't my device see an ad-hoc WiFi network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/why-cant-my-device-see-an-ad-hoc-wifi-network)

I created an ad hoc Wi-Fi network on my Windows XP laptop but I don't see it in my Samsung's network list. Why? I found instructions online on how to unlock ah hoc Wi-Fi support on Android. Is it really impossible to connect to ad hoc networks by default? What is the alternative? How can I connect my laptop and Tab?

**UPDATE**

I saw that ad hoc Wi-Fi is now called Wi-Fi Direct. Is this true? But settings for XP's ad hoc Wi-Fi are unrelated to Android's Wi-Fi Direct: the former requires an SSID and a key, while the latter requires only a device name. Also, Android's Wi-Fi Direct scanner sees no ad hoc network being published by the XP laptop.

Comment: WiFi direct is not related to Ad-hoc netwroks

Comment: So should Android support ad-hoc or not?