# Why can't android connect to an ad hoc hotspot?

Tags: ad-hoc-networks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can't my device see an ad-hoc WiFi network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/why-cant-my-device-see-an-ad-hoc-wifi-network)

One thing I have noticed about almost all android-powered smartphones is that they find it so difficult to connect to ad hoc wireless hotspots. I can connect most wifi enabled devices to this ad hoc connection(created with an iPhone 3G app, MyWi) but not android phones. Is there a fix for this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, this is something inherent to Android itself. I'd go further to say that if you've ever used an Android device that could access ad hoc WiFi it's something the manufacturer added.

I would love it if someone could prove me wrong on that though.

So as for why, I suppose only Google knows.

Comment: Same here can't believe this feature is still missing.