# How to share my laptop internet connection via wifi to my android tablet?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi, networking, reverse-tether, ad-hoc-networks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why can’t my device see an ad-hoc WiFi network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/why-cant-my-device-see-an-ad-hoc-wifi-network)

I created a wifi hotspot in my Windows 7 laptop (open ad-hoc) but my Android 2.3 tablet is not detecting it. My tablet is detecting other wifi networks but not my laptop's hotspot, how can I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't my device see an ad-hoc WiFi network?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/16575). See also: [Does any version of Android support ad-hoc connections?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16657/16575)

Comment: Hint: For more details, you might also follow the ad-hoc-networks' tag -- or hover your mouse over it and, on the popup, click on "FAQ" to have the questions ordered by "importance".

Answer (score 0):

As described in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/17071/12357) most versions of Android don't support Ad-Hoc WiFi networks, however if you try using an application such as [Connectify](http://usage.connectify.me/windows.html) then this should allow you to use your laptop's internet connection on your phone. If you need them then instructions on how to set it up can be found [here](http://mobileoffice.about.com/od/internet-sharing-tethering/ht/how-to-share-your-windows7-wifi-connection.htm).

Comment: Connectify .. is not free :(