# how do I connect an android phone to a Linux wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, linux

I am using my Debian Linux computer (called 'theresia') as a wifi access point.  I can use the network from iOS, Meego and Maemo, and from my other Debian machine obviously, but none of my Android devices even sees the signal.

from Debian, the icon for the signal is different than the access point produced by an Android phone (here, the nozhatu signal):

[image]

any clue?

Comment: That is Ad Hoc Network symbol. Standard Android does not support Ad Hoc networks.

Comment: I see.  so to solve the issue on the Android side, I have to go root each of the devices I want to connect.  to solve it on the Linux side, I have to produce a normal WiFi signal, right? (https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/4418/why-cant-my-device-see-an-ad-hoc-wifi-network is more informative.)