# Use USB as network access for an Android device (reverse tethering)?

Tags: usb, networking, usb-tethering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

Note I'm not talking about getting my PC network access through my Android device, I'm talking the opposite.

I sit in a dead spot at work and I'd like for my Android phone to be able to access a network over its USB connection with my PC. Does such a thing exist?