# Internet from Ubuntu to Android via USB

Tags: usb, linux, reverse-tether

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use usb as network access for android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/6479/use-usb-as-network-access-for-android-device)
>   [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

Is there any option to use the internet connection from my PC running Ubuntu (12.04) with my phone (Samsung Galaxy Ace Android 2.3.7 with root)?

I have tried many options to do it via wifi, but it still doesn't work (it is long story with my hardware and Galaxy Ace).

Comment: I'm closing this as a duplicate for now. If you make a compelling case that this is not actually a duplicate of the linked questions then this one may be considered for re-opening.