# How to access internet on my  HTC Desire from my pc with USB?

Tags: htc-desire, tethering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

Is there any way for enjoying internet on my android device without having WiFi or any thing else except USB.
Actually I have an internet connection on my PC. I am wondering if there is a way to share it from my PC for my Android phone. It is opposite of the normal "tethering" direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:
http://www.junefabrics.com/android/

If you have a rooted device maybe this would be a better option:
http://blog.mycila.com/2010/06/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22.html