# Share PC network with phone when connected with USB

Tags: usb, networking, reverse-tether

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

So, I know about tethering where I can share the mobile network with my PC.
I'm in the reverse situation - no mobile network and no wireless.

But my PC has a network connection. Can I share that with the android phone when the phone is conencted to the PC through the USB cable ?