# How to browse Internet in Samsung Galaxy Fit using Broadband in Windows 7?

Tags: reverse-tether, samsung-galaxy-fit

I have a Samsung Galaxy Fit smartphone and want to browse the web on it using BroadBand connection (the one i use for my pc connection to Internet) in Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb

Comment: i have checked that question and there seems no solution to that problem .There is an answer but its not working properly and question posted was one year back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From everything I have read about this topic, it is possible to do on a linux machine, but not with a windows machine. this could be because of something with ADB on windows, or the USB drivers for windows.

[Here](http://blog.mycila.com/2010/06/reverse-usb-tethering-with-android-22.html) is the info (note that this reference was done with a Nexus One):

- **Requirements:**

  - Android 2.2 (or an older version with a root tethering app)
  - ADB from Android SDK, or a rooted Android 2.2 with terminal in root mode

STEP 1:
Device: Connect USB cable and activate USB Tethering. You should see on linux new network interface.

STEP 2:
On Linux Computer, setup a bridge:

- usb0 is the new network intreface
- eth0 is the main interface connected to internet (or a gateway)

  $ sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0
  $ sudo ifconfig usb0 0.0.0.0
  $ sudo brctl addbr br0
  $ sudo brctl addif br0 eth0
  $ sudo brctl addif br0 usb0
  $ sudo ifconfig br0 up
  $ sudo dhclient br0

See [Network Connection Bridge Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge) to setup bridges

STEP 3:
Setup usb0 interface of your phone. You have to options:

1. From your computer, execute:

   ./adb shell netcfg usb0 dhcp
2. Or in a root terminal on your phone, type:

   su
   netcfg usb0 dhcp

You should now be able to connect to Internet on your phone using your computer's Internet connection.

Try to do a ping www.google.com to be sure

STEP 4:

To shut down the reverse-tethering, first unbridge interfaces on your computer:

```
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 down
$ sudo ifconfig usb0 down
$ sudo ifconfig br0 down
$ sudo brctl delbr br0
$ sudo ifconfig eth0 up
$ sudo dhclient eth0
```

Then on your phone, uncheck the USB Tethering option

Comment: on running ./adb shell netcfg usb0 dhcp ,i got error: device not found

Comment: i am using a DSL connection and upon running sudo ifconfig eth01 0.0.0.0, i got this
SIOCSIFADDR: No such device,so i renamed the connection to eth0 ,then it worked fine

Comment: i didn't switch off usb tethering

Answer (score 0):

The best and simplest idea in the long run would be to get a wireless broadband router that also supports ethernet (wired networking). Your pc can still use cables and your android phone just connects to it using wi-fi.

Without a wi-fi router you still have a few more options that work with Windows, as long as your pc has wi-fi (which you can get using a simple USB network card that costs less than 20 USD). In this case you have a few options (in order of recommendation):

1. Use software to turn your pc into a wifi router that shares it's internet connection. Instructions are available [here](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-share-internet-connection-between-pc-and-android-phone-using-wifi/).
2. Setup an ad-hoc network with Windows and then root your android phone to enable it to see ad-hoc networks using the instructions found [here](http://szym.net/2010/12/adhoc-wifi-in-android/).
3. Use Wi-fi Direct which is a new protocol that'll work with Android 4.0 and Windows 8 (not very helpful, I know).