# Let Android believe it is connected to internet

Tags: networking, internet, reverse-tether

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

Is there a way to do this?

I'm trying to reverse tether my Android phone. I'd like it to use my PC connection. Many guides on the net say that I should root my phone, but I don't want to do that.

What I would like to happen:

- connect Android to the Internet via wireless
- attach to PC via USB, in "tethering usb mode"
- PC is already connected to the Internet in another way (cable)
- when I disconnect the wireless connection on the Android phone, then the Android phone uses the connection of my PC

With no internet connection on my phone I can't connect successfully to the PC.
So, I'd like to know if there is a way to let the Android device believe it is connected to the Internet.

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: I'm interested in this too. It would allow testing applications on mobile without Wi-Fi or network connectivity.

Comment: @Audrius: you can do this using android sdk and Eclipse plugin. A "virtual android device" will be created on your PC, so you can test on PC all applications you develop, and you can also use the PC connection. Google to have more informations about :)

Comment: That is correct, but I want to test on a multiple physical devices and I can't afford buying multiple SIM cards and/or swapping them around.

Comment: I'm voting this question to close, it's difficult to tell how is this different from [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb). The OP should clarify whether he just want a reverse tethering or something more.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified if you have wireless capability in your computer. Assuming you have one or can manage wireless in your computer then you can take the following steps to share the computer's Internet via ad-hoc wireless connection.

First create an ad-hoc connection in your computer so that your phone can connect to it. You can follow [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Adhoc) guide for that.

After that you have to enable Internet connection sharing in your computer. Follwo [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing) guide for that.

Now from your Android phone search for the ad-hoc network you created and connect to it. Internet should work fine.

One more thing I should mention is that when I tried the same for my cousin it didn't work. The phone couldn't see the ad-hoc network. She had Windows 7 in her computer. But after little Googling and using 3rd party software for ad-hoc connection in the computer, everything worked.

Comment: it seems that Android isn't able to see ad-hoc wireless connection for security reasons. It is required a rooted phone to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this a while back when I first got an Android phone, but it didn't fully work. In windows 7 I use http://www.connectify.me and that works perfectly, so I never continued with it in Ubuntu.

Try these anyway:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessAccessPoint

http://www.esrun.co.uk/blog/ubuntu-gateway-access-point-server/

Let us know how you get on... would be interesting to know!

Answer (score 1):

The Replicant Project has a page on how to use [USB Networking](http://trac.osuosl.org/trac/replicant/wiki/ReplicantUSBNetworking); you'll need a rooted phone, the scripts there, and a GNU/Linux system to use the scripts with little to no modification.

However, it's a start.