# How to force Android 2.3 to believe that there is networking?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, networking

(unsatisfied by answers in ["Let Android believe it is connected to internet"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/11728/let-android-believe-it-is-connected-to-internet), they more about "how to set up networking")

The android device is connected to the Internet though my laptop over Wi-Fi in ad-hoc mode, not from any Android interface, configured from console (Android thinks that it is offline: both wifi and data transfer indicators are off).

All console tools, browsers, etc. see the network, but Google things (like Google Talk) show "Network currently unavailable. Will connect automatically when available" and [seems like] doesn't even try if the network is *really* unavailable. Google Market shows pages, but silently fails to download anything in this state.

How to explicitly tell Android that "there is network" without turning on Wifi or mobile networking?

Comment: I think we've had a question that was actually the same as this before, but I can't find it.  I've had much the same annoyance on pre-Android smartphones where apps don't understand that Wi-Fi means internet access even if I'm not connected to a cell data network.

Comment: Here the system (Google Talk, Google Market) sees that there are neither Wi-Fi nor call data connection (actually there is Wi-Fi, but with trickier setup) and does not even _try_ to use networking.

Comment: (Currently having to use airbase-ng to force my BCM4313 into "master" mode to be able to connect Android in usual way. This is inconvenient (unreliable, no encryption, low speed))