# Internet access from my Samsung G II through my office PC network via USB?

Tags: internet, reverse-tether

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

How do I connect and have internet access from my Samsung G II through my office PC network via USB?

Answer (score 0):

The [PDAnet](http://junefabrics.com/android/) app has always worked for me in getting internet over USB.  The only difference between the free and paid versions is that paid supports https.

Comment: I believe PDAnet is for tethering and @Yazid is asking for reverse tethering.

Comment: Mmm, quite possibly. The grammar is bad enough that it's hard to tell...

Answer (score -1):

Even I had tried but didn't work for me. However, you can try this:
http://www.linuxreaders.com/2011/03/09/android-access-internet-from-computer-via-usb/ 
Another option is to set up your laptop as a wifi hotspot. This might help- 
http://keithmac.com/?p=125

I have set up the same way at home without a wifi router. I have a wireless adapter on my desktop and set up an adhoc network and I can access my internet connection on my phone. But there's a catch. It might not work without rooting your phone.