# WIFI share a reverse tethered connection

Tags: reverse-tether

I know that it is possible to reverse tether your Android device via USB thanks to questions like [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb). But I am hoping to take this a step further by then sharing that connection to others via WIFI - like a bridge essentially.

I haven't seen this anywhere else and wondered if it was even possible? Has it been attempted and failed to anyone's knowledge?

Comment: It should be possible, the Wi-Fi chip should be free to broadcast.  Very likely that there aren't any phones that come with software to support using the USB connection rather than the cell connection, though, so you'll need something custom.  Whether that exists is the question :)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible somehow, but IMO if you have the devices that need to share connection, you'd do well by investing on a dedicated portable Wi-Fi hotspots. It will be much less if a hassle. At the very least, you should use your phone instead of the laptop as the gateway.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to do what you want with only an Android device, but since you mention reverse tethering using USB you could achieve the same thing using only a *computer that has an internet connection* and *wi-fi*. You can use your computer's wi-fi to share your internet connection with multiple devices, including your android phone, using one of two methods:

1. [Setup your computer to be a virtual wireless router](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-share-internet-connection-between-pc-and-android-phone-using-wifi/). All devices could then share internet by connecting to your computer using wi-fi.
2. Setup an ad-hoc wireless network, but unfortunately Android devices will only be able to connect if you set them up using these [instructions](http://szym.net/2010/12/adhoc-wifi-in-android/) that require your phone to be rooted.

If you *don't* have wi-fi on your computer, then a PCI or USB wi-fi network card is generally quite cheap to obtain.

Comment: Thanks @Silveri but I am looking for advice on doing this with an android device not computer with Wifi.

Answer (score -2):

well i too got an idea to reverse tether and make my android as a portable wifi hotspot but when reverse tether is done u need to switch your mobile data connection so that it appears as if you are using your data connection but the internet is used from reverse tethering your pc net try it if it works then good