# UDP multicast with reverse tethering

Tags: networking, reverse-tether

We are using a Wi-Fi network to communicate with other devices running our applications. And, we are using `UDP` multicasting.

However, due to some new restrictions we are no longer allowed to use wifi.

Is there a way to connect all the devices (via `USB`) to different computers (connected to the same local network) and have them all receive and send data with `UDP` multicasting?

We don't need internet, just the LAN. This is only used for testing purposes.

---

I am looking at this post about [reverse tethering](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb). Has anyone used `UDP` multicasting with this setup? Will the mentioned method solve my problem?

We do not currently have a linux machine setup and it would take us a **while** to get one setup. So if anyone could confirm this, from experience, before we start doing down that road, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Your question is very specific and IMHO you are following the wrong approach. It seems like you are in a situation where using multicast is just no more adequate. You want to forward the multicast packets form a PC via *reverse* tethering to an connected Android device. I am pretty sure that this would require some sort of specialized daemon software running on the PC (and maybe even on the Android device). I think that this question is to localized.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going the whole "multicast over reverse tethering" way, which to me, doesn't make any sense at all, you should evaluate if a **VPN setup with multicast enabled** (plus optionally reverse tethering) may be a solution to your problem.

<sup>On a second thought: VPN + reverse tethering *is basically* "multicast over reverse tethering"</sup>

Comment: We are not allowed to have a VPN.