# Using Laptop's internet on Android Phone

Tags: internet, reverse-tether

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

We all know as to how to connect our android phone with our laptop so as to use our laptop's internet connection in our android phone.

But my question is how to be directly connected to internet on the laptop and connect my Samsung Galaxy Y mobile to it, so as to use the laptop's internet connection in the mobile.

---

Reason: Why I need to do that.
I Live in the country of India. MTS was the first country to launch 3G Plug-and-Play Modems in India. I have one of those. The device has a direct connection and does not requires insertion of a SIM card. I can connect it to my Laptop and use the internet service, but it is not possible to connect it to the mobile phone.

P.S: Fell free to migrate it to SuperUser if you guys think it belongs there.

Comment: That's called Reverse Tethering. There have been several questions on here about it. I'll search for a dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a rooted device, [Reverse Tether](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.littlelan.ReverseTether.Paid&hl=de) can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Turn your laptop into a WiFi hotspot. See [Turn Your Windows 7 Laptop into a WiFi Hotspot with Connectify](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/9739/turn-your-windows-7-laptop-into-a-wifi-hotspot-with-connectify/) as an example. In a GNU/Linux system, use `hostapd` for this purpose. (Actually, if you don't like the idea of writing a configuration file for `hostapd`, the popular NetworkManager tool also supports managing an AP now, but this is not available through its GUI tools; it requires a manual tweak in its configuration file for `mode=ap`. ">Reference in Russian.)

Then use WiFi from your mobile phone to connect to the laptop's WiFi.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: Doesn't connectify provide ad-hoc network only? If so, this requires a rooted Android device, as most Android devices do not support ad-hoc otherwise.

Comment: @Izzy What about the connection sharing provided by Windows? Control Panel > Network and Sharing Center

Comment: Don't ask me about Windows -- I only use them to watch out, or open them for fresh air ;) But AFAIK the place you describe is just about *what* to share (e.g. the "permissions" part to share a folder), not the *how* (which is what the OP is looking for). Otherwise, what would you need connectify for?

Comment: Actually, if you don't like the idea of writing a configuration file for `hostapd`, the popular NetworkManager tool also supports managing an AP now, but this is not available through its GUI tools; it requires a manual tweak in its configuration file for `mode=ap`. Reference in Russian: http://www.altlinux.org/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0#.D0.A1.D0.BE.D0.B7.D0.B4.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D1.83.D0.BF.D0.B0_.D0.B2_NetworkManager