# Is it possible to connect my Android device to my computer's internet?

Tags: internet, reverse-tether

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

If I have a workspace with no WiFi, but I do have an internet enabled computer (through an RJ45 cable), is it possible to get an android device bridged to the computer's internet using a micro-usb cable? It looks like ADB has some point to point features, but all I could find is how to share individual sockets and not the full shabang. Although, I can't say I fully understand the `adb ppp` command I found on SO:

`adb ppp "shell:pppd nodetach noauth noipdefault /dev/tty" nodetach noauth noipdefault notty localip:remoteip`

There might even be some voodoo with adb forward?

Comment: Have you looked at [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2298) (or the other questions in the [reverse-tether](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether) tag, for that matter)

Comment: I added the `reverse-tether` tag. Just follow the link edaderathis was giving, and also click the tag to see more related questions and answers.

Comment: I assume it depends on the computer. I think a Mac will share its connection over Bluetooth.