# can't find setting static IP or Enable android reverse tethering

Tags: wi-fi, 4.1-jelly-bean, internet, usb-tethering

I have a nexus S and Android 4.1.2, I want to share a wifi connection from my laptop (ubuntu 13.04) and connect to it from my Nexus S, But.. I can't find where can I set a static IP address on my device.

I've also tried the reverse tethering, and I don't find where can I enable it on my device.

Thank you :)

Comment: May want to look at [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb) if you can't get WiFi to work.

Comment: It must be done on the ubuntu laptop, as that is supposed to be the AP. Try searching for `ubuntu share wifi`.

Comment: thank you @ott-- I have configured my laptop, it's now the turn of my android device.. it doesn't recongnize the wifi

Comment: Can you make a screenshot where it shows the available WLANs?