# How can I download apps from Google Play to my Tab using my PC's Internet connection?

Tags: google-play-store

I don't have access to the internet on my Samsung Tab 3 and don't have wifi either. Only my PC has internet access through a landline and non wireless modem. How can I download apps from Google Play to my tab? I got the USB cable that connects my tab to the PC.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is "reverse tethering". [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

Comment: That would most likely require the device to be rooted, which is not always an option.

Comment: Reverse tethering sounds like too much work. I'd just buy a micro-usb to ethernet converter online if I were you. There should be no need to root your device either.

Answer (score 0):

While one solution might be to setup reverse tethering, as eldarerathis already pointed out in his comment to the question (see: [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/2298/16575)), this most likely requires your device to be rooted.

An alternative approach is described in an Article I've recently stumbled upon: [How to extract direct APK links from Google Play Store](http://lemmymorgan.com/how-to-extract-direct-apk-links-from-google-play-store-android-market/). This basically uses a Java app on your PC, which is connected to your device via USB cable – and hence would perfectly match your needs.

You would need to download that Java application ([Real APK Leecher](http://lemmymorgan.com/how-to-extract-direct-apk-links-from-google-play-store-android-market/real-apk-leecher-v1-3-5/)), install it on your PC, configure it with your device ID (which you can find e.g. via the "dial code" `*#*#8255#*#*`), and then this Java app pretends to be your Android device, so you can use it to browse the PlayStore and download apps to your device.

Disclaimer: I didn't try this for myself, so I'm just sharing my find with you here.