# Why is there no option for USB INTERNET in WIRELESS & NETWORK SETTINGS on my Nexus 5?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, usb-connection-mode, reverse-tether

I own a Nexus 5 with Android KitKat 4.4.2. I have been trying to do reverse tethering without root as is supposedly possible from Settings → Wireless & Networks → More → USB Internet. But I can't see any USB Internet option in Wireless & Networks. Why not ??

Can someone assist me with this ? I am having a PC with Windows XP.

Comment: So you are basically trying to use the computer's internet connection on phone or you want to browse the internet on comp using the phone's data network?

Comment: I am trying to use internet on my mobile after connecting it to PC (reverse tethering) .... And i want to do it without rooting the phone ... This should be possible with USB Internet ... But that option is not visible ... why ???

Comment: This option is called "Internet Pass-through". I think is only present in HTC devices by default. I don't remember this option on my nexus when I had KitKat. Do you have any screenshot of where you have noticed this?

Comment: See [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable) question. This option should be visible in my Nexus 5, but it isnt

Comment: Hmmm, as I said those are device specific. This is the first time I'm noticing it on a Micromax device. It is not present in Google's KitKat or any other Android OS by default. Chcek this - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1371345&page=155

Answer (score -1):

In Android 4.4.x you should be able to find the USB Internet option under:

```
Settings --> More... --> Tethering & Portable Hotsport --> USB Tethering
```

[image]

If you want to later on configure your network sharing settings so that your device can benefit from the shared internet connection, please read [this stack answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-windows-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable).

Comment: OP asked for [reverse tethering](/tags/reverse-tether/info) – you showed "tethering". Please follow the link to see what's the difference and why your post doesn't answer the question. Hint: it's the direction.