# How do I access PC's internet on Android Phone?

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, reverse-tether

I'm using Android Jelly bean 4.2 (Micromax Canvas 2 Colours). I've a PC at home which has internet connection. I don't have any wireless router or any access point. I just want to use PC's internet connection on my android phone. Kindly help me.

Comment: May be you should head out over the discussion over the stack exchange [PC internet on Android Phone through USB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable). I guess its already discussed over there. Maybe you should have a look over their, I can't bet over those tricks but some of the tricks shared by users can be of your use.

Comment: Peter is right. In case you need to do closer research: the process is called "reverse tether" (I've added the corresponding tag to your question).