# How to use PC internet in to android phone using usb cable

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, reverse-tether

I want to use my PC broad band Internet in my android device using USB cable because my pc has not any Fifi or blue-tooth so I want to connect with standard USB cable and Used my pc Internet. if any suggestion then let me know.

Comment: Search and research on Reverse tethering.

Comment: As @Firelord already suggested: that's called reverse-tethering. I've added the corresponding tag to your question; please click that to see other questions using this tag, and you'll find things like [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2298/16575) and, more recent, [How to use PC's internet on android phone through USB cable](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/73168/16575) (almost the same title as yours, and should be a good match hence ;)