# Reverse Tethering (USB) through Windows 10 using Android 4.2.2 without installing additional software

Tags: windows, reverse-tether

I want to use the Internet Connection of my Windows 10 PC with my Android-Device through USB-Cable.

How can I reverse tether through windows 10 using my usb-cable?

I have found some [similar questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable), but the question and its answers are telling me how to use the Android SDK to do USB-Tethering. I don't want to install additional software like the Android SDK.

It sounds, like there was an built in solution in windows, but the necessary sharing tab is missing:
[image]

Is there really no way to do usb-tethering using Windows 10 without installing external software like the Android SDK?