# Xperia Z3 Android 6.0 : How to share my computer internet with USB?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internet, usb-connection-mode, sony-xperia

Having troubles sharing my internet connection from my desktop computer to my Xperia Z3 compact phone. I went to `Settings` -> `Network connections` -> `USB connection`. From [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable) (a bit old, it's meant for KitKat and not Marshmallow), I expected to view an option like `USB internet`. But there is only an option called `Software install` that I checked. But what software is this option about and how to install it, I don't get it.

I tried to connect my phone to my Windows 10 computer after checking the option, nothing special comes, no software install. I can choose several options :

- charging only
- transfer files (MTP)
- mass storage (MSC)
- MIDI

Choosing MTP, I can move files from my computer to my phone. But unlike what is presented in [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable), no additional network connection do appear on my computer. I tried to share my connection (because my computer have two Ethernet ports, I can activate it anyway), but that does not work. No internet on my phone.

Sorry if the menus or options from this post are not strictly the same in the english version, my phone is in another language. Anyway, What I describe should be clear enough (otherwise just say, I'll explain more deeply).

Can anyone help ? I guess it's something special to Sony phones, or maybe it did change from Android 4 to Android 6, but I'm a little confused...