# Connect PC net to android without wi fi modem

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

Pls tell procedure to Connect PC(window 7) net without wi fi modem to android version 6.0.1 model Moto G4 Plus

Comment: See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73168/how-to-use-pcs-internet-on-android-phone-through-usb-cable and other questions under the [tag:reverse-tether] tag.

Answer (score 0):

You want to connect Win7 to mobile network? you want to whats called USB tether . theres lots of guides and youtube videos for this.