# Enable “USB Internet” for Android 6.0

Tags: internet, windows, usb-tethering, reverse-tether

With earlier versions of Android, there was the option to connect your mobile phone via USB cable with your Windows PC and enable "USB Internet" to share the internet connection from your PC with your phone (in case you don't have Wi-Fi nor Mobile Data). But with Android 6.0, this option is no longer available from the settings.

Is there a way to a) enable this setting again or b) share the internet connection (reverse tethering) via additional mirroring apps (all without hacking/rooting the phone)?

Comment: Have you considered the ReverseTethering NoRoot app as described in this [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/143914/2241)?

Comment: Well, I had a look at it. But you need to install Java JRE, USB Drivers, Servers, etc - all of that really need some additional know-how which is everything else than an easy solution.

Comment: After some sweat it really worked! But I would still prefer the simple "Enable USB Internet" option which worked with earlier Android versions. Running a server on my PC is just not what I want to do in general. Also, you reach very easily the limit of the app (max. 10min) and need to buy the "Pro" version, so it is not really a nice option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Not* using Reverse Tethering NoRoot, there are two ways to make reverse tethering.

#### Method 1:

It requires Android 5.0+, a 20KB .apk to install, and a command-line PC program (1MB).

You can use [Gnirehtet](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet) (It is similar to Reverse Tethering NoRoot, but uses less space and has no usage limit), which can be [downloaded here on GitHub](https://github.com/Genymobile/gnirehtet/releases). You will also need the [ADB tools](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/) in the same folder.

#### Method 2:

It works with all versions of Android (without ADB), but requires Windows 10. It, again, will require a program on your Android device *and* PC.

[This article](http://salutepc.altervista.org/usb-reverse-tethering-no-root-no-adb-android-all-versions-windows-10.html) explains how to create reverse tethering using OpenVPN. It will take much more space on your devices (and much more time setting up everything), but it also works.