# reverse tethering over USB on Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 with Android 4.4.2 (kitkat)

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, reverse-tether, samsung-galaxy-tab-4

if got a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 (SM-T530) with Android v4.4.2 (kitkat).
The Tab is rooted over Odin.

I wants to use reverse tethering over usb-cable from a PC.

I tried now 2 days, but nothing works. The main Problem is, that the 
setting for usb tethering didn't appear. Samsung kick out this function
for the tablets.

I also tried to install tethering Apps. But without the settings nothing did.

At the pc (linux, ifconfig) no usb network interface appear...

Does anybody got a solution? Other Android versions working with Galaxy Tab 4 and got the usb tethering feature?

Would be nice if anybody have an idea for my problem....

Comment: Have you tried the solutions [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2298/1465)?