# Getting message "Unknown id: netcfg" while setting up usb0 interface for reverse tethering

Tags: networking, tethering, shell, reverse-tether, usb-tethering

I am trying to setup reverse tethering between Sony Xperia 4.0.4(rooted) and Linux 12.04. I'm following steps from Matthew Read's answer on this post, [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)

All steps work but when I execute "su netcfg usb0 dhcp" in root shell of phone then I get message "Unknown id: netcfg".

> 130|root@android:/ # su netcfg usb0 dhcp
>   
> Unknown id: netcfg

I'm not sure what this message means and how to fix it. I could not find anything related in Google search. Can anyone please guide me about it.

Comment: Matthew's answer is from 2011, so it's definitely pre-ICS. My guess is that the `netcfg` command was renamed/removed meanwhile. Try replacing it by `ifconfig` (i.e. `su ifconfig usb0 dhcp` and see if that works (pointer taken [from here](http://redmine.replicant.us/boards/9/topics/2859)). In the worst case, that might throw another error message. You could also check whether there's a similarly named executable (e.g. by typing `net` followed by a "<tab>", if your terminal/keyboard supports that – or by walking through the `/system/bin`, `/system/xbin` etc. directories).

Comment: I tried ifconfig but same result.

Comment: Urgs. My bad. You've got an error in your command, try `su -c "netcfg usb0 dhcp"` (first non-option parameter to `su` is the user to switch to; with `-c` you rather advice it to execute the command).

Comment: @Izzy, thanks! It fixed the error. You can add it as answer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Answer posted. I will now also update Matthew's answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight syntax error in your statement: the first non-option parameter to `su` (which stands for "Switch User") is the user to switch to (if omitted, `root` is assumed). So your `su netcfg usb0 dhcp` basically advises `su` to "switch to the user `netcfg` – but there is no such user.

To fix it up, just use `su -c "netcfg usb0 dhcp"` – which would, due to the non-existent "first non-option argument", would advise `su` to switch to `root` and then, by the `-c` parameter, execute the **C**ommand `netcfg usb0 dhcp`. Further note the command is *quoted:* this is required as it contains (white) spaces.