# Reverse Tether Android Tablet without Rooting

Tags: wi-fi, router, tethering

What are some ways I can use an Android Tablet's USB cable to leech off a PC's wired internet connection?  I have a PC with fast and unlimited internet and I want to connect an Android Tablet to it *without* using Bluetooth or Wi-Fi.

Additionally, I do *not* want to "root" the Android Tablet.

Comment: Based on [the answers on this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb?rq=1), I'm afraid you do need root. Hopefully there's another way...

Answer (score 0):

You certainly don't need to root it. Unless you're a farmer.

On your PC go to start >control panel.

Go to Networking and settings Center, and then clicking Manage network connections. Right-click the connection that you want to share, and then click Properties. There should be a share option.

Comment: the question is about reverse tethering. i.e. being able to use the internet that you computer or laptop is using **from** an android device via USB. Not sharing your mobile data connectivity with your computer