# reverse tethering - offline for some applications

Tags: networking, offline, reverse-tether, dns, iptables

I try to get internet on my phone from my computer without instlling any tools.

My configuration looks like :

```
mybox -----(Ethernet)------[my computer]------(USB)-----[the phone]
```

I enabled usb tethering so I have two interface on my computer : eth0 and usb0.

I read
[How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2298/how-to-set-up-reverse-tethering-over-usb)
and I have done :

One the computer:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0  
sudo ifconfig usb0 0.0.0.0  
sudo brctl addbr br0  
sudo brctl addif br0 eth0  
sudo brctl addif br0 usb0  
sudo ifconfig br0 up  
sudo dhclient br0
```

On the phone :

```
su
netcfg rndis0 dhcp
```

After that I have :

```
IP of rndis0 on the phone : 192.168.1.22/24
IP of br0(eth0 + usb0) on my computer : 192.168.1.21/24
IP of the box : 192.168.1.1/24
```

When I try to do a ping on the computer and on the smartphone, it works :

```
ping 8.8.8.8
```

But if I try to ping on a domain it work on the computer but not on the phone:

```
root@hammerhead:/ # ping google.fr
ping: unknown host google.fr
```

Ok so maybe a dns problem of the smarphone? (I don't believe on it because it is obtain by dhcp and the ping work on the computer):

```
root@hammerhead:/ # getprop | grep dns  
[dhcp.wlan0.dns1]: [192.168.1.1]
[dhcp.wlan0.dns2]: []
[dhcp.wlan0.dns3]: []
[dhcp.wlan0.dns4]: []
[net.change]: [net.rndis0.dns2]
[net.dns1]: [212.27.40.240]
[net.dns2]: [212.27.40.241]
[net.rmnet0.dns1]: []
[net.rmnet0.dns2]: []
[net.rndis0.dns1]: [192.168.1.1]
[net.rndis0.dns2]: []
root@hammerhead:/ # ping google.fr
```

Also, some applications (youtube, chrome) say I'm offline.

Then my questions are : why these applications say I'm offline when I can do `ping 8.8.8.8` or another addresses? and why the ping of a domain doesn't work?

Of course, I can give you more informations if you want

EDIT (new information)
Also when i delete all rules except unreachable :

```
root@hammerhead:/ # ip rule show
32000:  from all unreachable
```

and if I try `ping 8.8.8.8` it give me `connect: Network is unreachable` which is normal. but when i try `ping google.com` I get `ping: unknown host google.com`. So a ping to a domain just doesn't reach the 'routing stage'. I can have the same behaviour on a linux machine where /etc/resolv.conf is empty but on my android I get the DNS from the dhcp server of my box. When i connect my phone to my box with wifi it work fine with dhcp...

Thank you

Comment: just an additionnal remark : when i do `ping google.com` there is nothing on usb0 (unlike to `ping 8.8.8.8`) So it seems there is something blockink my ping when it is a domain...

Comment: I solved the dns problem by using ndc. but know I can browse any website with chrome application but youtube application still tells me I have no connection. I don't know why

Comment: Can you tell how you solved the dns problem using `ndc`?