# How to setup a reverse USB tethering connection (multiplatform)?

Tags: usb, 7.0-nougat, reverse-tether, usb-tethering, dhcp

I've tried to setup a reverse USB tethering connection to share an internet connection from a macbook to a smart phone running Android 7.0 using [this tutorial](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=69925269) but I can't seem to get there 100%.

Here's what's working:

- HoRNDIS-rel8 install (restart was required)
- Tethering & portable hotspot > USB tethering is enabled / Tethered Enabled Internet
- Sharing from WiFi to Android device Android device appears connected
  via DHCP in Network Preferences pinging works both ways (from OSX to
  Android and back) route works and outputs something like this:

  Destination: 192.168.42.0, Gateway: *, Genmask: 255.255.255.0, Flags: U, Metric: 0, Ref: 0, Use 0, Iface: rndis0

[image: Internet Sharing to Android]

[image: Android Phone DHCP]

What doesn't work:

- netcfg is missing
- pinging google.com or accessing anything from the internet doesn't work

I've tried running `route add default gw 10.42.0.1 dev rndis0`
which resulted in

```
route: resolving 'gw'

I've tried disabling the other shared interface (which weren't connected anyway) such as USB Ethernet and Thunderbolt Ethernet,
disabling/re-enabling USB tethering but the Router for this interface in Network Preferences is still `192.168.42.129`, just the IP changes.
```

Any hints of what I might be missing or how I can make this work ?

Thank you,
George

Comment: See if the first part of my answer here works for you: http://android.stackexchange.com/a/6480/1465

Comment: You could also try my app ReverseTethering NoRoot that's available from Google Play.

Comment: @MatthewRead That works! The simple-rt-cli application doesn't seem to support hot-plugging, but at least it's open source and can be tweaked.
Thank you

Comment: @FD_ I've tried your app: pretty slick! Minimal simple UI: what's not to like :D
I couldn't figure out: what's the cost of the Pro version ? Also, can I re-use the same license my other android devices ? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation purposes here is an expanded version of the comments.

Option 1: [**SimpleRT**](https://github.com/vvviperrr/SimpleRT) does work and the device gets an IP on the local network which is a plus. On the downside, it supports a single android device and doesn't support hot-plugging at the moment, however, the software is free and open-source (another plus)

Option 2: **Reverse Tethering NoRoot**. 
I've tried the [free app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.reversetethering.free&hl=en_GB) and it's a great app: minimal easy to understand UI, the server app on desktop is brilliant in it's simplicity. It supports multiple clients and hot-plugging (great pluses to have). At the moment it doesn't look like the android device gets an IP on the local network which would be great feature.

In conclusion: if you simply need to connect multiple android devices to the internet via USB and don't mind the lack of a LAN IP for the devices, Reverse Tethering NoRoot is the easiest option.